# Redirect in badrequest

Tags: java, forms, playframework-2.1

I have a problem.

I have form in play framework and when I want open new, I use this link: `link/projeto/novo`

There are some fields that I need to save and I do one validation and If there some field blank, I send one "badrequest", like this:

```
    public static Result grava() throws IOException{

    Long id;

    Http.Request request = request();

    Form<Projeto> projetoFormRequest = projetoForm.bindFromRequest();
    listaDeErros = new ArrayList<String>();

    Projeto projeto = projetoFormRequest.get();

            if(StringUtils.isEmpty(projeto.getNomeProjeto())){
        listaDeErros.add(Messages.get("projeto.form.validacao.nomeProjetoObrigatorio"));
    }

    if(projeto.getTipoProjeto().getIdTipoProjeto()==null){
        listaDeErros.add(Messages.get("projeto.form.validacao.tipoDeProjetoObrigatorio"));
    }

...

    if(listaDeErros.size()>0){
        return badRequest(cadastro.render(projetoForm, listaDeErros));
    }
...
```

My routes:

```
GET     /projeto/novo     controllers.ProjetoController.cadastroProjeto() 
POST    /projeto/grava    controllers.ProjetoController.grava()
```

but my link in browser change to `link/projeto/grava`

I'd like to maintain the same link `link/projeto/novo`

How could I do this ?

thanks

Comment: show us your routes for `link/projeto/novo` and `link/projeto/grava` links

Comment: GET         /projeto/novo                                           controllers.ProjetoController.cadastroProjeto()
POST        /projeto/grava                                          controllers.ProjetoController.grava()

Answer (score 0):

As you are returning `badRequest()` in the `grava` action it stays there... `badRequest` is a `Result` **NOT** a `redirect`.

You can try to redirect to the `cadastroProjeto` in case of error, anyway you'll need to pass `projetoForm` somehow, maybe using cache?

TIP: *It's good habit to use English names for actions, models, views, etc - even if routes are Portuguese ;)*